Zero percent test coverage after upgrading to Springboot 3
we have recently started upgrading our systems to Springboot 3.
For some reason, all my Junits are showing a Test coverage of 0% in sonarqube whereas the threshold to pass the pipeline build is 80%. SonarQube fails my build and its hard to figure out the what the issue is despite having plenty of Junits written in the code.
Using Sping boot 3.2.5, Maven 3.8.8 in Azure Pipeline using SonarQube and The following test package versions -
We use JDK17
What I have tried doing - upgrading the junit and jacoco version


<jacoco-maven-plugin.version>0.8.11</jacoco-maven-plugin.version>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
<artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
<version>**5.9.2**</version>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
<artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
<version>**4.1.0**</version>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<plugin>
<groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
<artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>${jacoco-maven-plugin.version}</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>coverage-initialize</id>
        <goals>
            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
    <execution>
        <id>coverage-report</id>
        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>report</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
    <execution>
        <id>coverage-check</id>
        <goals>
            <goal>check</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <rules>
                <rule>
                    <element>PACKAGE</element>
                    <limits>
                        <limit>
                            <counter>LINE</counter>
                            <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                            <minimum>0.00</minimum>
                        </limit>
                    </limits>
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>



Really need help to figure out what we may be doing wrong.
